# jquery autocomplete doesn't work?

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete

I want to make autocomlplete for remote data source, I get all data from database and return it as jSon, using console I see that all data has been returned, but the autocomplete doesn't work, also the alert in my code doesn't work, here's my code

```
$("#cellPhoneNo").autocomplete({

    source: function(request, response) {
        var param = {
            "action": "getCellPhoneNos"
        };
        $.getJSON("controllers/Customer.controller.php", param, function(result) {
            alert('here'); //doesn't alert
            //  cellPhoneSource=result;
        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert('response');
    }

});
```

**EDIT**

I try to get the source using GET , I make like this

```
source:function(request,response){
            var param= {"action":"getCellPhoneNos"};
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "controllers/Customer.controller.php",
            data: param,
            success: function(result){
            alert('success');
            }

            });
            },
```

it alerts but autocomplete doesn't work, I try to put the values in a text file and make the file in the url , the autocomplete works!!

Any explanation?!

Comment: which autocomplete jquery plugin do you use? Put URL here.

Comment: I recommend to use [this one](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/)

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the one from jQuery UI?!

Comment: I am using autocompleter from jQuery UI version jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min

Comment: @Thief, OK, this is something new, I started with jquery 1.3.2 2 yrs ago, and I hand't reason to upgrade since.

Comment: Autocomplete _does_ work. You made a mistake.

Comment: @Tomas: That's ridiculous. You should stay up-to-date as a matter of course, especially if you're going to be responding to jQuery questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tomalak, I don't see any reason 4 upgrade and switch to different autocompleter, when I maintain projects, which are perfectly working. Don't see anything ridiculous on that. There's nothing much fabulous in the new versions... beside that the documentation got completely broken as of 1.4, luckily I have mirror of the old one.

Comment: @Tomas: Bug fixes and continued community support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/

This is a tutorial on using the autocomplete plugin.  The `response` variable in your callback is a function that you can call to add an array of items to the autocomplete list.  Parse `result` and push each item onto an array, then call `response(array);`  If result is already an array, you can call `response(result);`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in the success function you do not return the result from the ajax query, could that be an issue?

```
source : function(request,response) {
     var param= {"action":"getCellPhoneNos"};
     var source = 'nothing came back from the server';

     $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "controllers/Customer.controller.php",
          data: param,
          datatype: 'json'
          success: function(result) {

            if(result !== undefined) {
                 source = result;
            }
            alert(source);
            return source;
          }

     });
},
```

Comment: ' return source' cause an error which is 'source is not defined
[Break On This Error] return source; '.

Comment: add datatype : 'json' to the ajax settings